# Instance as a static class property

Tags: php, static

Is it possible to declare an instance of a class as a property in PHP?

Basically what I want to achieve is:

```
abstract class ClassA() 
{
  static $property = new ClassB();
}
```

Well, I know I can't do that, but is there any workaround beside always doing something like this:

```
if (!isset(ClassA::$property)) ClassA::$property = new ClassB();
```

Comment: [This has been asked multiple times before.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984360/php-property-as-object) [Properties cannot be initialized with runtime dependent information.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) Set the instance in the Ctor. Or lazy load it in a Getter.

Comment: Yes, I know I can set it in a constructor, but in my case I need a class to be static. Thanks for an effort though :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern ?

Comment: @Paulius you can also set static properties in the ctor, so I dont see a reason for the "but".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you can use a singleton like implementation:

```
<?php
class ClassA {

    private static $instance;

    public static function getInstance() {

        if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
            self::$instance = new ClassB();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }
}
?>
```

then you can reference the instance with:

```
ClassA::getInstance()->someClassBMethod();
```

Comment: I'd rather not call it getInstance though but rather getB() then.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative solution, a static constructor, is something along the lines of

```
<?php
abstract class ClassA {
    static $property;
    public static function init() {
        self::$property = new ClassB();
    }
} ClassA::init();
?>
```

Please note that the class doesn't have to be abstract for this to work.

See also [How to initialize static variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693691/php-how-to-initialize-static-variables) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/3313137/118153.

Answer (score 0):

This is a few years old, but I just ran into a issue where I have a base class

```
class GeneralObject
{

    protected static $_instance;

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        $class = get_called_class();

        if(!isset(self::$_instance))
        {
            self::$_instance = new $class;
        }

        return self::$_instance;
    }
}
```

That has a Child Class

```
class Master extends GeneralObject 
{

}
```

And another Child class

```
class Customer extends Master 
{

}
```

But when I try to call

```
$master = Master::getInstance();
$customer = Customer::getInstance();
```

then `$master` will be `Master` as expected, but `$customer` will be `Master` because php uses the `GeneralObject::$_instance` for both `Master` and `Customer`

The only way I could achieve what I want was to change the `GeneralObject::$_instance` to be an `array` and adjust the `getInstance()` method.

```
class GeneralObject
{

    protected static $_instance = array();

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        $class = get_called_class();

        if(!isset(self::$_instance[$class]))
        {
            self::$_instance[$class] = new $class;
        }

        return self::$_instance[$class];
    }
}
```

I hope this helps someone else out there. Took me a few hours to debug what was going on.