# Why can't we use the "new" keyword in a class property?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Instance as a static class property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9159202/instance-as-a-static-class-property)

I got a problem about creating an Object in a class as an attribute.

```
include 'Bar.php';
class Foo()
{
    private $bar = new Bar();
}
```

It comes out a parse error. But when I put the $bar outsite class

```
include 'Bar.php';
class Foo()
{
    //private $bar = new Bar();
}
$bar = new Bar();
```

No syntax error. works perfectly. So what's the problem. I just ported my Java knowledge to PHP. Sometimes, its so confusing.

Comment: It's not possible; there is a long discussion on why, check it out:[Why don't PHP attributes allow functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3960323)

Comment: more: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[php]+body%3A%22initialization+must+be+a+constant+value%22

Comment: @Gordon the question linked above is the only thing close to a canonical explanation attempt. I know of no more; might just upvote your dupe-link so it becomes more visible in the close dialog... Do you think it's worth adding to the Tag Wiki?

Comment: @Pekka IMO the tag wiki is worthless because no one looks into it, but sure, go ahead and add it ;) Though I think it would make more sense to go through the search, hijack one question, rewrite it and have the good answers merged into it.

Comment: @Gordon will do. We should be able to close questions as a duplicate of the Tag Wiki. *That* would increase its visibility :)

Comment: @Pekka I'm still convinced it needs subpages (like Operator reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put it into the constructor:

```
class Foo() {
    private $bar;
    function __construct() {
        $this->bar = new Bar();
    }
}
```

Comment: Object property of an abstract/base class must be initialized in every constructor of every inherited class. Very annoying.

Comment: Just call the parent constructor, and it will do the job...

Comment: Nice, but it is easy to forget this.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Foo {
    private $bar;

    public function __construct() {
      $this->bar = new Bar();
    }

    public function check() {
      return $this->bar->checkBack();
    }
}

class Bar {
  public function __construct() {
    print "good\n";
  }

  public function checkBack() {
    return "checked";
  }
}

$f = new Foo();
print $f->check();
```